# Rendering ValidationError from pre_delete signal in admin form?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-signals

I'm trying to trigger a nice error that appears in the admin backend when you try to delete a model instance. If I use the following signal to do this, my problem is that it throws a 500 error instead of posting a nice error message inside the form:

```
@receiver(models.signals.pre_delete, sender=MyInvincibleModel)
def execute_before_delete(sender, instance, using, *args, **kwargs):
    # some logic
        raise ValidationError("Nooo, I don't want to die!!")
```

If, however, I raise a ValidationError in the model's clean method, it DOES appear as a nice error message in the form itself. The problem with doing it this way is that I don't know how to make the clean method check to see if an instance is being deleted. If I had a custom ModelForm setup, I could do something like this:

```
for cleaned_data in self.cleaned_data:
    if cleaned_data.get('DELETE', True):
        raise ValidationError("Nooo, I don't want to die!!")
```

But I want to rely on the standard admin forms and prefer to avoid overwriting every single one where deletion might occur.

My question is: how can I make the validation error thrown by the pre-delete signal render nicely in the admin form or, failing that, how can I make the model clean method detect when data is being deleted?

Django: 1.6.1
Python: 3.3

Comment: The admin's deletion is handled by a separate view, which has nothing to do with the form of your model view. And worse, for bulk delete, the signal won't be fired. So you may need to overwrite admin's delete action.

Comment: I tested this and found that the signal I outlined above is actually triggered even during bulk delete, so not sure what you mean by that. I also tried modifying ModelAdmin.delete_model() but the error it generates is still thrown as a 500 / debug with traceback rather than a nice message. If you want to write up an answer with your suggestion (and it works) I'll happily accept it!

Answer (score 0):

This proved to be quite a bit more difficult than it should have been, but I found a solution by overriding both ModelAdmin.delete_model (in case a user accessed a single instance of the object via the hyperlink) and the delete_selected action (in case the user tried deleting using the change_list) and putting my logic in there.

Comment: What logic did you actually put in there? Raising an exception? Did it come back as a 500, or a nice message?

Comment: Just FYI when I overrode delete_model and delete_queryset (Django 4.2), raising an Exception would give a 500 error.  I had to override get_deleted_objects, and append error messages to the "protected" return value.